# Using nearbySelection in VehicleRouting results in a Mimic exception

Tags: optaplanner

I'm trying to implement a CVRPTW based on the Optaplanner Vehiclerouting example (6.2.0-CR4).

Optaplanner is a great project to work with!

To speed up the search for a decent solution I started to experiment with nearbyselection. But when I configure the use of the CustomerNearbyDistanceMeter the following exception is thrown:

> Exception in thread "1271a58a-a134-4b68-b485-f6e678307357" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Replay must occur after record. The recordingEntitySelector (Recording(Filtering(FromSolutionEntitySelector(Customer))))'s next() has not been called yet. 
>       at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.entity.mimic.MimicReplayingEntitySelector$ReplayingEntityIterator.next(MimicReplayingEntitySelector.java:104)
>       at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.entity.nearby.NearEntityNearbyEntitySelector$RandomNearbyEntityIterator.next(NearEntityNearbyEntitySelector.java:203)
>       at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.entity.decorator.FilteringEntitySelector$JustInTimeFilteringEntityIterator.createUpcomingSelection(FilteringEntitySelector.java:107)
>       at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.common.iterator.UpcomingSelectionIterator.hasNext(UpcomingSelectionIterator.java:40)
>       at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.common.iterator.AbstractRandomSwapIterator.(AbstractRandomSwapIterator.java:35)
>       at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.move.generic.SwapMoveSelector$2.(SwapMoveSelector.java:125)
>       at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.move.generic.SwapMoveSelector.iterator(SwapMoveSelector.java:125)
>       at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.move.composite.UnionMoveSelector$RandomUnionMoveIterator.(UnionMoveSelector.java:140)
>       at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.move.composite.UnionMoveSelector.iterator(UnionMoveSelector.java:125)
>       at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.decider.LocalSearchDecider.decideNextStep(LocalSearchDecider.java:112)
>       at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.DefaultLocalSearchPhase.solve(DefaultLocalSearchPhase.java:66)
>       at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.runPhases(DefaultSolver.java:213)
>       at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:176)
>       at com.itmatic.optimisations.app.VehicleRoutingTask.run(VehicleRoutingTask.java:103)

I configured things as follows:

```
 <constructionHeuristic>
    <constructionHeuristicType>FIRST_FIT_DECREASING</constructionHeuristicType>
  </constructionHeuristic>
  <localSearch>
    <unionMoveSelector>
      <changeMoveSelector>
          <entitySelector id="entitySelector1"/>
          <filterClass>com.vos.optimisations.solver.move.CustomerChangeMoveFilter</filterClass>
          <valueSelector>
            <nearbySelection>
              <originEntitySelector mimicSelectorRef="entitySelector1"/>
              <nearbyDistanceMeterClass>com.vos.optimisations.domain.solver.nearby.CustomerNearbyDistanceMeter</nearbyDistanceMeterClass>
              <linearDistributionSizeMaximum>1000</linearDistributionSizeMaximum>
            </nearbySelection>
          </valueSelector>
      </changeMoveSelector>
      <swapMoveSelector>
        <entitySelector id="entitySelector2"/>
        <filterClass>com.vos.optimisations.solver.move.CustomerSwapMoveFilter</filterClass>
          <secondaryEntitySelector>
            <nearbySelection>
              <originEntitySelector mimicSelectorRef="entitySelector2"/>
              <nearbyDistanceMeterClass>com.vos.optimisations.domain.solver.nearby.CustomerNearbyDistanceMeter</nearbyDistanceMeterClass>
              <linearDistributionSizeMaximum>1000</linearDistributionSizeMaximum>
            </nearbySelection>
          </secondaryEntitySelector>
      </swapMoveSelector>
      <swapMoveSelector/>
      <subChainChangeMoveSelector>
        <selectReversingMoveToo>true</selectReversingMoveToo>
      </subChainChangeMoveSelector>
      <subChainSwapMoveSelector>
        <selectReversingMoveToo>true</selectReversingMoveToo>
      </subChainSwapMoveSelector>
    </unionMoveSelector>
    <acceptor>
      <lateAcceptanceSize>600</lateAcceptanceSize>
    </acceptor>
    <forager>
      <acceptedCountLimit>10</acceptedCountLimit>
    </forager>
  </localSearch>
</solver>
```

What does the exception mean and why is it being thrown?

**UPDATE:** I removed the filterclasses but the mimic exception is still being thrown.

The exception occures only when the SwapMoveSelector is in place!!

Comment: On first sight, the config looks ok. Try removing 1 of the 2 MoveSelectors to determine which of the 2 selectors is causing the mimic problem. Then try removing the filter class (although that shouldn't have any impact) and see if it reoccurs. Report that diagnostic info here.

Comment: Mimic selection is explained in the ref manual (no image yet though :). The error happens when the mimic selector is called before the original - which should never happen in this config.

Comment: Also add the entire stacktrace pls.

Comment: Hi Geoffrey, thanks for your suggestions on this matter.

Comment: I have been removing the filters, but the exception is still being thrown. The execption is caused by the swapMoveSelector. When i remove only the swapMoveSelector everthing works just fine!

Comment: Interesting, this could be a genuine bug, so I want to investigate this problem. Is there a way you could isolate a reproducer and attach it to a [jira ticket](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER)?
If it's a bug, I want to fix it for 6.2.0.Final, but then I need to be able to reproduce before Monday afternoon...

Comment: any news on this? I just [pushed](http://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/compare/a19c8d2...6e1878c) the docs for this, but I can't explain your bug - it could be genuine. I need to be able to reproduce by tonight if you want to fix to make 6.2.0.Final.

Comment: Sorry for the absence of a reply, i've been ill for a couple of days. But i will be starting to work on this again today.

Comment: Thanks. I 'll need a reproducer to be able to fix it (if it is indeed a bug) or an cause description (if it's user error that can be avoided with better docs)